# Domain Access - restrict content for only authenticated users (and keep domain specific settings)

Tags: users, domain-access

I have a site using domain with multiple subdomains.

I want to display some of the particular domains. I can do this with the "Publish to *" field in the domain access options. How do I also restrict access to some content types so that only authenticated users can access these content types and also work with domain access?

I had the module content_access installed to prevent ANONYMOUS USERS from viewing specific content types but this was causing problems with domain as it would write to the node_access table realm=all & view=1 for all content types. This meant that all domains could get access to the content even though the check boxes were set to one specific domain. I think the node_access permission logic is connected with OR.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the issue was with the content_access module. It was overriding the settings for the domain access.

Once this was turned of domain was able to operate as designed with just the 'publish to ...' settings.